# How can I tell what version of Windows came on a laptop?

Tags: windows, windows-7, certificate, licensing

I have a HP G61 Laptop model number `g61-511wm` that has two stickers on top: `AMD` & `Windows 7`

I don't have the restore disk for this computer, however on the bottom there is a certificate of authenticity. The part where it say the product name has been rubbed off, but the number is still legible.

I would like to figure out what version of Windows 7 was originally on the computers so I can install that and use the product key.

**Is there any way I can figure this out, perhaps by looking up the product key?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your notebook came with Genuine Windows 7 Home Premium 64-bit
http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?docname=c01868469&cc=us&dlc=en&lc=en

You can make your own HP Recovery media, use high quality DVD+R discs
http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?cc=us&lc=en&docname=c01867124

How to recover your PC
http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?docname=c01895783&cc=us&lc=en&dlc=en

All your support Documents
http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/product?product=4034514&lc=en&cc=us&dlc=en&task=&lang=en&cc=us

You don't really need that product key on the sticker (HP Recovery installs a different key automatically), but you may want to record that key before it rubs off and store it someplace safe, it can be used to install W7 from a regular W7 install disc (which HP will not supply).

Comment: @cwd refresh this page, I did an edit to my answer to include another link

Comment: Is there a way I can download the recovery disk creator instead of having to get HP to e-mail the disks to me if the hard drive was replaced? I didn't see the download link in the second link you provided - just instructions. did i miss it?

Answer (score 1):

Contact HP.  They will have the details of the original system configuration including the version of windows that shipped on the workstation.  Newer workstations that are shipping don't have recovery media, but a recovery partition built-in.  All you will need is HP's phone number (or however you prefer to contact them) and the serial number of the hardware.

Answer (score 0):

Run the program WinVer.exe

Also, you can paint the windows version in the bottom right corner of your desktop using this method :

```
User Key: [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop]
Value Name: PaintDesktopVersion
Data Type: REG_DWORD (DWORD Value)
Value Data: (0 = disable, 1 = enable)
```

Comment: Erm, or just go to the system properties dialog box.

Comment: It is a detailed version number, which you can't get from the properties box.   its the same version you get when you run the program  WinVer.exe .

Comment: The only thing missing in the system properties dialog box is the build number, which does not change from one version/service pack to the next. In any case, the question the OP asked was "what version was installed by the OEM", not "what version is installed now". Service packs and such change the version.

Answer (score 0):

There is no official Microsoft way of finding out the product key used to activate your license. If this is an OEM laptop then the product key is actually tied to the motherboard and BIOS which makes it difficult to reinstall. If that is the case the product ID on the bottom of the laptop is not actually the one used to activate the laptop and you are out of luck. There may be some "unofficial" ways to find your product ID from the registry but I'm not going to list them here.

Comment: the old hard drive is non-functional so this isn't an option anyhow. thanks.